# Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Id at line 10 column 46

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
public class SharinPixWorkOrderTriggerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testSharinPixWorkOrderTrigger() {
        WorkOrder fieldVisit = new WorkOrder(Job_Name__c='Visiting Green Field');
        Test.startTest();
        insert fieldVisit;
        Test.stopTest();
        List<WorkOrder> expectedfieldVisit = [
                                                    SELECT Id, SharinPix_Token__c
                                                    FROM WorkOrder
                                                    WHERE Id = :WorkOrder.Id
                                                    LIMIT 1
                                                ];
       System.assert(expectedFieldVisit[0].SharinPix_Token__c.length() > 0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your query, `Id = :WorkOrder.Id` should be `Id = :fieldVisit.Id`

The [binding operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) works with a record not with SObjectType.

```
// WorkOrder.Id returns field API name as Schema.SObjectField data type
// this is used mainly with dynamic apex
// where as query filter expects a primary data type
Schema.SObjectField Id = WorkOrder.Id;
```